# "git push": slug compilation hangs

Tags: django, git, heroku, pip, heroku-toolbelt

This issue started today for no apparent reason. When I do `git push dev master` for my Django project, I sometimes get a hang after the program says "installing dependencies with pip":

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 643 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
-----> Using Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
```

After 15 minutes of hanging, compilation times out.

Then I run the same command again (without having changed anything), and it works. I suspected it was a problem installing one of the modules in my requirements.txt file, but I made that file empty and the problem still occurs.

My logs just show this:

```
heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
```

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Looks like a common problem others are having too (including myself). https://status.heroku.com/ isn't much help. I pushed once this morning and it worked, but for the most part, I'm running into this as well. Extending the compile time duration doesn't help.

Comment: Few! I thought I was the only one. I had checked Twitter, and that website, but they said everything was normal, it's good to see it's not just me. :)

Comment: @RexE , if you have a paid account, do you mind asking customer support what's up, and then posting what they say here? (I have a free account - so I can't contact them)

Comment: @GangstaGraham I have a free account too :(

Comment: same issues here its stuck

Comment: Same issue. Just commenting so hopefully others don't spend an hour trying to fix it, like I did! I tried creating whole new app from scratch and still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a far shot, but ... you could try

```
git fsck --full --strict
```

to make sure your repository is healthy.