# Cant upload my application with Django in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, push, pip

I'm trying to upload my application in heroku but when i try to do the first push I get this:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.4.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.4)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.36)
-----> Installing Pip (1.3.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.3.1)
```

then, the proccess stop working for a long time and it neve finish. After 15 minutes I got hits:

```
 !     Timed out compiling Python app (15 minutes)
 !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit
```

What can I do?

My requirements.txt is like that:

```
Django==1.5.2
argparse==1.2.1
distribute==0.6.24
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: Based on your [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552846/no-web-processes-running-django-in-heroku) it looks like you're a step further. Did you get this problem worked out?

Comment: I have the same issue with Heroku currently. This question has some more comments and seems like many others are having an issue too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550219/git-push-slug-compilation-hangs?lq=1